# Method not found on release build

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable, methodnotfound

Lately, I encountered a slowdown in my website and already found the cause. The reason behind is because the methods in my DA layer has IEnumerable parameters instead of IQueryable. I already refactored the parameters in my DA and the solution was built successfully. However upon replacing the dll of DA in prod, the error method not found happened in the BL layer. The method it was looking for was the previous which has the IEnumerable parameter. Why am I encountering this when I built the code in my solution without fail?

NOTE: I did not replace any other dll except for the DA

Comment: Is it strong-named?

Comment: Uhuh. What do you mean strong named?? Sorry there are still lots of terms im not familliar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I encountering this when I built the code in my solution without fail?

Because you're rebuilding your BL project as well, presumably. That's fine - the method still exists *by name*, and the new parameter type is presuambly compatible with the argument you're passing, so your source still compiles.

But when you try replacing *just* your DA assembly, when your BL assembly code executes, it's still looking for a method with the `IEnumerable` parameter, but that method doesn't exist any more, hence the exception.

Simply put, changing a method parameter type is not a backwardly-compatible change, in terms of *binary* compatibility.

Just rebuild the whole project, and replace *everything* that depends on your DA assembly, as well as the DA assembly itself. Ideally, replace absolutely everything you build - that way you know that you've got a consistent set of assemblies.

Comment: Ooh wow!! Maybe this explains why when I did the opposite (built my BL, reverted my DA), method still not found but now it looks for the IQueryable. Gotta check this out

Comment: @JanLyndonJasa: Fundamentally, I would encourage you to redeploy *everything* you rebuild, rather than one assembly at a time. That way you know the set of assemblies is consistent.

Comment: Can't say much to a Jon Skeet answer, however, I'd like to add if you call a method. The runtime will find that method based on the SIGNATURE you called. Since parameters are part of the signature you'll not be able to call it if they change.

Comment: @NoëlWidmer: The runtime is also sensitive to the return type, which isn't part of the signature in C# terms.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, thanks for the lesson. Wasn't aware of that! :)

Comment: @NoëlWidmer: I had to check it myself before adding the comment :)